# how do i duplicate the nobody user?

Tags: linux, permissions

how do i duplicate the nobody user?

i have a couple of webprojects and need to chown the diffrent projects to 
diffrent users with absolutly no privileges

i currently use nobody on a project. works fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest adding the users manually in /etc/passwd. Take a look at the nobody-line, it should be something like

```
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
```

Add another line, change the ID and you should be good to go.

```
nobody2:x:65533:65533:nobody2:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
```

Or if you would like to use a command, this should do it:

```
useradd nobody2 -d /nonexistent -s /bin/sh
```

Comment: Though this will work, I generally suggest you avoid manually editing that file.  Use the tools like useradd.  If you want to manually edit, consider at least using vipw, which is a tool that will check that your changes are valid.

Comment: I can understand your point off view, you are right, if you screw the file, you're a long way from home... Added the command ;-)

Comment: I would further suggest NOT using "nobody" usernames -- there's an old joke that "nobody" is the second most privileged user on a system, after root.  Give the users a meaningful username and GECOS fullname to distinguish them from each other.

Comment: Also true, You might even want to change the shell to /sbin/nologin. Like that he will be unable to login.